# Running a django project on windows server 2016 - IIS

Tags: django, iis, windows-server

I’m trying to run a django site on windows server 2016. I am using IIS and FastCGI to do this. After trying to open the site in the browser, I get this error message:

```
Error occurred while reading WSGI handler: traceback (most recent call last).:File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 791, in main env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response. physical_path) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 633, in read_wsgi_handler handler = get_wsgi_handler(os.getenv("WSGI_HANDLER")) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi. py", line 605, in get_wsgi_handler handler = handler() ^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\django\core\wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application django.setup(set_prefix=False) File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\django\__init__. py", line 24, in setup apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS) File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 83, in populate raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant") RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant StdOut:
```

I tried adding enviromental variables which didn't help but maybe I didn't set them correctly.

I would be very grateful for advice and guidance on how to fix this error.

Have a nice day

Lukas

Comment: There are many reasons for this error, what version of python do you have installed? Is the python installation path correct?